# Deprecated error output disappear after first time

Tags: php

I use php 7.2

It's my actions step by step:

1. If I load the below script first time I won't get any error output.
2. If I make a syntax mistake and reload the script again I'll get **Parse error** output.
3. If I fix the syntax mistake and reload script I'll get this message:

> **Deprecated**: Non-static method First::run() should not be called
>   statically in /var/www/test/index.php

4. Finally, If I reload the script again, without any fixes I won't get
   any error messages and the script will work correctly.

Could you explain me why the Deprecated error disappears?

```
error_reporting(E_DEPRECATED);

class First {
    public function run() {
        return 'run';
    }
}


$result = First::run();

echo $result;
```

Comment: I assume you have opcache enabled?

Comment: Pardon me but What is the question by the way?

Comment: "*There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things."*

Comment: Try running this via the CLI instead, you'll avoid a lot of potential caching issues

Comment: @Andrew You are right. Disabling helped, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `run` function is not static.
Just make it static like this `public static function run()`.

Regarding your question that why that thing happened, frankly I don't know but you can prevent it from happening by above or by disabling the [OPcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php)